# Extracting polygon from several feature classes in one process using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, clip, features

I've built a polygon and used Clip (Analysis Tools) in order to extract information from several feature classes that intersect the polygon. Of course, I used the clip tool for each feature class.

My boss wants a single tool that clips all these feature clases at once and saves the result in different FC.

Is there a tool in ArcMap that does that?

Select by Graphics is cool, but then I have to export the data "manually". I've created this model, but in the case of the model I don't have the liberty of selecting the area I want to clip every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Split by Attribute](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14127), [Split (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000006000000), or if you want to get fancy you can write your own Python script to do this using the following ArcPy methods:

1. Use `os.walk` to walk through all files in a defined directory
2. Loop and search for files that end with ".shp"
3. Create a feature layer of your clip layer
4. Use `arcpy.SearchCursor` loop and grab all unique values via a split field to base your split on
5. Use `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management` to select each unique feature
6. Use `arcpy.Clip_analysis` to clip against feature layer and input layer (layer to be clipped)